# Where can I download and use the AddressBookUI.Framworks?

Tags: objective-c, addressbook

I want to write an application about the address book UI in **iPhone**. I found that there are a framework which is AddressBookUI. But where can I find this framework? Do I need to download or found form somewhere? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is  part of system. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/addressbook/reference/addressbook_iphoneos_framework/index.html

Comment: thank you for your reply. I know this is part of the system, but where can I add into the Frameworks folder. As I download some sample code form the apple, I found that there are framework shown in the left hard mean bar and under a folder called 'Framework'. The problem is I cannot found that framework in my application. As I have some code in the project already, I cannot re-create the project, would you mind to show the steps how to add it? Thank you.

Comment: sorry for typing wrong, I want to ask the AddressBookUI, not the AddressBook, thank you.

Comment: I found how to download it. I found the sample code form the apple and add the framework in my Mac.